# Can some explain how many times is the print statement being executed

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

```
 // For the below algorithm, calculate the exact number of times
   // System.out.println statement is executed as a function of n. Assume n≥1

    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < 2*n; j++) {
    System.out. println(”1 iteration executed!”);
    }
    }
```

This is the solution but I am having a hard time understanding the math.

```
Overall RT = 2n + (2n-1) + (2n-2) + … + n =
 = (n+1)*n + (n+(n-1)+(n-2)+…+1+0) =
 = n2 + n + n*(n+1)/2 =
 = 1.5*n2 + 1.5n
```

Comment: More of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand? Do you see why it's `2n + (2n-1) + (2n-2) + … + n`?

Comment: Is it because the inner loop runs for 2n and runs (2n-1) after each iteration of outer loop. The next 3 lines I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop runs 2n times the first iteration, and then 1 less each time until the (n+1)'th iteration when it runs `n` times.

```
2n + (2n-1) + (2n-2) + … + n
```

Note that there are `n+1` terms in this series.

Let's subtract `n` from each term and add them separately. This gives us `(n+1)*n` plus each term minus n:

```
(n+1)*n + (2n-n) + (2n-1-n) + … + (n-n)
```

This simplifies to:

```
(n+1)*n + n + (n-1) + (n-2) + … + 0
```

Now, it's [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn) that the sum of `1+2+3+...+n` is `(n+1)*n/2`, and that's exactly what `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + … + 0` is:

```
(n+1)*n + (n+1)*n/2
```

Now we can just multiply it out:

```
n^2 + n + (n^2)/2 + n/2
```

Which simplifies to:

```
1.5n^2 + 1.5n
```

Answer (score 0):

So lets step through this. Lets say the value of n is 4.

`i` starts at `0` so `j` also starts at `0` this time
`j` increment until 1 less than `2*n` which is 8
This means the values of `j` this time will be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`, a total of 8 different values

`i` increments to `1` so `j` starts at `1` this time
`j` will still increment until 1 less than `2*n` or 8
The values of `j` this time around will be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`, a total of 7 different values. That's 1 less than last time!

The next time around, the values of `j` will be `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`. 6 different values.

This pattern will continue until `j` starts at `4`. Then `j` will take on 4 different values and the loops will exit.